# How to count array with the same month

Tags: php, mysql

```
$dates = array('2017-03-24 01:48:09', '2017-03-24 11:48:09', '2017-04-07 01:12:19', '2017-04-14 01:49:09', '2017-04-21 01:45:09', '2017-04-28 01:38:09');
```

if given array above..

i'm making a report to monitor user growth monthly.. i want to count the no. of entries per month

sample April 2 counts

Comment: will Jan 2017 and Jan 2018 be on the same count? Or this is assuming that entries on the array have the same year?

Comment: ...and is this data already inside a MySQL table?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: The code snippet in the OP would require use of substr()  However, if you tell us more - you may get a better response.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dates = array('2017-03-24 01:48:09', '2017-03-24 11:48:09', '2017-04-07 01:12:19', '2017-04-14 01:49:09', '2017-04-21 01:45:09', '2017-04-28 01:38:09');
$count = array();
foreach ($dates as $d) {
  $count[date('m', strtotime($d))]++;
}
print_r($count);
```

Output will be:

```
Array ([03] => 2 [04] => 4 )
```

That is: `03` (March) has 2 values in given array.

If you need `03` as `March`, then use:

```
$count[date('F', strtotime($d))]++;
```

Then, output will be:

```
Array ([March] => 2 [April] => 4 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dates = array('2017-03-24 01:48:09', '2017-03-24 11:48:09', '2017-04-07 01:12:19', '2017-04-14 01:49:09', '2017-04-21 01:45:09', '2017-04-28 01:38:09');
foreach($dates as $date)
    $year_months[] = date('Y-m', strtotime($date));
var_export($year_months);
var_export(array_count_values($year_months));
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => '2017-03',
    1 => '2017-03',
    2 => '2017-04',
    3 => '2017-04',
    4 => '2017-04',
    5 => '2017-04',
  )array (
    '2017-03' => 2,
    '2017-04' => 4,
  )
```